# BSOD when installing Server 2012 R2

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, installation, bsod

I have a RD430 server with a newly created RAID 10 partition which i would like to intsall server 2012 r2 on (previously installed 2008 r2). After I start the server up with the Lenovo Easy setup start up disc and configure all the different settings (server name/ip adres/RAID controller drivers etc and I insert my Windows installation disc the server reboots and crashes (BSOD) at the Windows boot screen. I have tried this multiple times and it keeps repeating. I can't read the BSOD error(code) because it disappears quickly. Does someone know what could cause this?

Comment: faulty hardware, faulty driver, faulty installation medium. the bsod message would surely be helpful. Take your phone and record a video of the boot process, it could be possible to read it from the video.

Comment: Windows Server 2012 R2 isn't listed as a supported Operating System for that model. - http://shop.lenovo.com/us/en/servers/thinkserver/racks/rd430/#tab-tech_specs

Comment: That's true but the drivers for the Server 2012 R2 OS are available on the lenovo support site and I also have a RD330 with the same OS tech specs but I succesfully installed 2012 R2 on it..

Comment: Guys I installed Server 2012 on it and updated it to 2012 R2 with a service pack..